# iPhone, how can I add a first view, show once, to a mainWindow but not have a tab bar button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I need to have a view which shows first before other views but doesn't have a tab bar button.

Is there a way to do this ?

EDIT:
I don't want to show it modally as i want to use to standard function which show other views and having to cater for different ways of showing the view would be messy.

Comment: What do you mean by "shows first"?  Do you mean on the top layer?  Or do you mean is shown for a brief time and then removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add your tabBarController in your window only once you need it and then remove your view from it's superview do discard it and free memory.

Something like:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void)showTabBarController {
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [viewController.view removeFromSuperView];
    self.viewController = nil;
}
```

Comment: So you're meaning to add the tabBarControler in a navigationController? This I believe is not allowed, but you could try to have one root view, that would allow to reach a TabBarController (with animation or not) that could contain as many navigationController as tabs.

Comment: Could you provide us with some code, because I believe as far as you add your views in a given order in your window, the top added would be on top layer and hide the tabBarController's view, hence it's tabs. Then dismissing it would just be a button or whatever action.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the tab bar to be visible, yet none of its items should be active and the visible view is not a part of the tab bar hierarchy? I don't think this is possible...

And even if you make things look like the described scenario, I have some doubts whether apple will approve an app circumventing standard functionality like this.

Comment: Ok then. I know you don't want to present your view modally, but I think this would be the perfect solution for you - maybe without using transitions, if that's what you don't like about them. For one of my apps I am using a modally presented VC to show a disclaimer before allowing the user to see the tab bar and it's views. Works perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

You mean UITabBarController?
Try use View Based Application or Navigation Based Application when creating the project in XCode

Comment: Still you can choose e.g. View Based Application and add the tab bar manually when neccessary and make a pointer onto it in your appdelegate